# Does $fopen function in Verilog support user argument?

Tags: verilog

Can I use a parameter for the file name argument to the `$fopen` function in Verilog?

For example:

```
handle=$fopen("filenam1");
handle=$fopen("filenam2");
handle=$fopen("filenam3");
...
handle=$fopen("filenam250");
...
```

I want to parameterize the argument of the `$fopen` function using something like this:

```
handle=$fopen("filenam%d",i);
```

The above code gives me a compile error:

> string filename;

Answer (score 3):

Yup:

```
module something();

string filename;

initial begin
    for (int ii=0; ii<20; ii++) begin
        int hFILE;
        $sformat(filename, "file%0d.dat", ii);
        hFILE = $fopen(filename);
        $fclose(hFILE);
    end
end

endmodule
```

And in Verilog 1995:

```
module something2();

reg [10*8:1] filename;
integer ii;
integer hFILE; // file handle

initial begin
   for (ii=0; ii<5; ii=ii+1) begin
       $sformat(filename, "file%0d.dat", ii);
       hFILE = $fopen(filename);
       $fclose(hFILE);
   end
 end

 endmodule
```

Comment: I just have been trying to implement above code. But I have got a compile error at this here.  string filename;

Comment: @ddol - this is SystemVerilog code so you may have to set the appropriate switch for your simulator. It's usually -sv or something.

Comment: No. May be you know , I want to do in Verilog not system verilog.